# @Component not being read in Spring test

Tags: java, spring

I created an Integration test to test the new feature I just added but the Spring wiring is not working. The unit tests all work and the existing Spring integration tests still work but I am unable to Autowire my new class

Here is the error message –

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx.xxx.etc.MyNewClassTest’: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.xxx.etc.MyNewClass ' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

The new class –

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyNewClass extends AbstractRetryJob<Event> {
```

My test -

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyNewClassTest {
  @Autowired private MyNewClass sut;
```

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` is not enough to create the Spring context.  You need to add `@SpringBootTest` to your `MyNewClassTest`.  Per the appropriate comment, you can drop `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyNewClassTest {

  @Autowired private MyNewClass sut;
}
```

Comment: To nitpick, @SpringBootTest includes @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) so it should be replaced rather than added.